# Live integration into (legacy) Chat, with direct Whisper messages to the Agents. Possible?

Tags: liveagent, chat, livechattranscript

I’m currently working on a solution that integrates within Salesforce to enable our systems to proactively assist Customer Service Agents, handling Cases and Chats through Salesforce. For this, we require:

1. A webhook / Trigger whenever an update occurs on a Case or Chat
2. A way to get the entire Case or Chat history through an API
3. A way to write and post an internal note through an API

For Cases, we have it all figured out and implemented, but now we’re looking into incorporating Chat as well.

Does anyone know if the three requirements above could be feasibly met in the live Chat environment? We’ve seen Whisper messages available, but haven’t been able to find them to be available on any of the API’s. Also, it seems it might only be possible to add a Whisper msg if an Agent has raised a Flag, and/or through Omni Supervisor.

So, I’m hoping someone here can advise if this is even possible, and to point us to the right resources to start figuring out how to implement this. As so far it feels like we’ve read through all relevant docs we could find, went through GitHub to see if we could find reference code somewhere, and checked w/ Salesforce support directly, but all have been unhelpful so far unfortunately…

TL;DR:

- can the 3 requirements from above even be met for Live Chat
- where could we find resources to get this done?